# Wireless ADB is connecting forever after wifi turned off and on

Tags: wireless-debugging

I connected my Watch (Galaxy Watch5) to wireless debug to Android Studio (latest), with "Pair using pairing code".

Everything worked perfectly, but the watch turned off its wifi, and obviously the debug procedure exited.

After I turned back on the Wifi on the watch, Android Studio keeps connecting for a few minutes then fails:

[image]

What can I do to prevent this? I don't want to reboot my computer every single time when the watch decides it's too warm for it to keep the wifi on.

(With Tizen watches I had never had any issues like this. Great improvement.)